# Why does Laravel think I am logged in as normal guard instead of my custom one?

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a custom guard called 'business_user' in my Laravel app by adding the provider into my auth.php file.

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

     'business_users' => [
         'driver' => 'eloquent',
         'model' => App\BusinessUser::class,
     ],
],
```

In my blade template I have some custom code which display different content depending on the user that has logged in.

```
@if (Auth::check('business_user'))
    <a class="btn btn-light" href="{{ route('user.logout') }}">Logout Business</a>&nbsp;
@elseif(Auth::check())
    <a class="btn btn-light" href="{{ route('user.logout') }}">Logout Customer</a>&nbsp;
@else
    (Guest user)
@endif
```

Whether I am logged in as a normal user OR the a business user the blade template always shows the first condition (Logout Business).

I have verified the correct user guard is logged in because I can verify this checking the session variable names in my laravel debug bar.

Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `check` method does not take arguments. If you want a specific guard that is what the `guard` method is for:

```
Auth::guard('whateveryouwant')->check();
```

In short your `if` condition and `elseif` were checking the same value. When you call `check` directly on the `Auth` facade the Auth Manager will use the default guard as the guard and call that method on it. (The default guard can change at run time; the `auth` middleware will set the default guard)

Also, you are showing the user providers not the guards that are defined. A guard would be a combination of a provider and a driver.

Comment: Thats weird so I used your code and its working, but you are right I've only created providers and not any guards, why does the code still work as expected?